# react-i18next, add resources from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have repo with components and repo with main app. I implemented i18next in repo with components and it works fine when I have an i18n config file in this repo (or when I pass it by props from app repo). But I have a problem when I'm trying to send only "resource" part from main app and replace it in config file in components. I tried to clone i18n instance and set resources but, it's not work.
It's my config file:
i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import LngDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { reactI18nextModule } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(LngDetector)
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .init({
    detection: {
      order: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
      lookupLocalStorage: 'i18n_lang',
      lookupCookie: 'i18n_lang',
      caches: ['localStorage'],
    },
    load: 'current',
    fallbackLng: 'en',

    ns: ['components'],
    defaultNS: 'components',

    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ',',
        },
        react: {
          wait: true,
     },
  });

export default i18n;
```

resources.js file (I tried with resources key at beginning but it's still doesn't work):

```
import * as en from './en.json';
import * as de from './de.json';

export default {
  en: {
    components: en,
  },
  de: {
    components: de,
  },
};
```

Now I tried something like this:

```
import * as langs from './resources';

const newI18 = i18n.cloneInstance({ resources: langs });

const i18ProviderDecorator = (storyFn) => (
  <I18nextProvider i18n={newI18}>
    { storyFn() }
  </I18nextProvider>
```

When I pass i18n.js by props with resources, it works perfect, but I want to remove i18next from main app and leave it only in the components.
Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a i18next cloned instance uses the same store as the original instance -> and does not init that again -> so passing in resources that way does not work: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/src/i18next.js#L308

make a new instance i18n.createInstance or pass resources to clone using i18n.addResourceBundle: https://www.i18next.com/api.html#addresourcebundle